# Is it possible to pass the evaluated result of one template tag as a parameter to another tag?

Tags: python, django

I have a custom template tag that takes a couple of key/value pairs.

```
{% mycooltag arg1=something arg2=somethelse %}
```

This works as expected for simple arguments. However, I would like to be able to pass `mycooltag` the contents of a template variable. Something like:

```
{% mycooltag arg1=something arg2={{ myobject.body }} %}
```

But this one doesn't work as expected. I get `{{ myobject.body }}` as a `string` rather than the actual contents of `myobject.body`. Is there a way to pass template variable into a template tag?

Comment: Have you tried `{% mycooltag arg1=something arg2=myobject.body %} `?

Comment: @Ngenator yep. No luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use simple_tag

```
@register.simple_tag(take_context=True)
def some_simple_tag(context, arg1, arg2):
    # do some work
    return 'string result for template to display'
```

in your template:

```
{% some_simple_tag something myobject.body %}
```